# SharePoint Rest API ValidateUpdateListItem not working with multi line field

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I am using SharePoint REST API to update the values in columns in document library. Below is the code.

```
var url= "http://mycompany.sharepoint.com/site1/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('My Library')/Items(7)/file/listitemallfields/ValidateUpdateListItem";
$.ajax(
    {
        'url': url,
        'method': 'POST',
        'data': JSON.stringify({
            'formValues': [
                {
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.ListItemFormUpdateValue' },
                'FieldName': 'NoteCol','FieldValue': 'Test Value'
            }
            ],
            'bNewDocumentUpdate': true,
        }),
        'headers': {
            'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'X-RequestDigest': $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
        },
        'success': function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        'error': function (err) {
            console.log(err.responseJSON.error.message.value);
        }
    });
```

The above code is working fine if the `NoteCol` column is of **TEXT** type. But my requirement is to make the column of type **MULTILINE**. But the above code is not working if I am trying to insert more than 255 characters which should not be the case as 255 characters if the limit for TEXT type column.

Any idea what is going wrong..

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Multiple Lines of Text

Comment: All these things are fine. It is not working when the value have more than 255 characters

Comment: have u updated the type of the column or created a new column

Comment: I have created a new column

Comment: did you checked the "Allow unlimited length in document libraries checkbox." while creating the column in document library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating multi line text in document library if you don't check the 
**Allow unlimited length in document libraries checkbox."**
then field validate you with limit of 255 characters.

Comment: One more thing...while we are creating this column through REST Api, what is the parameter that will set this limit..?

Comment: Dont have with rest but you refer the link http://mosstechnet-kk.com/how-to-change-a-multi-line-text-field-to-allow-unlimited-length-in-a-document-library/